# This app is not compatible with your device on Android TAB

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

When i'm trying to install app from market on my tab Motorola Xoom running android version 3.1.
  i also got same bug while installing app by downloading from market on PAD running android version 4

help will be appreciated...

below is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    package="com.clubdango.android"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="2.0.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ClubDangoApplication" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <!-- REQUIRED -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- REQUIRED for C2DM -->
    <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.clubdango.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.clubdango.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

</manifest>
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablet are xlarge screen in most case, you have to add `android:xlargeScreens="true"` to the supports-screens. Also, you have to provide xlarge layout and xhdpi resources if needed.

Comment: please can you explain, it won't allow me to download the app?

Comment: main prob. is when i'm downloading it from market on device it shows msg "this app is not compatible with your device" 
Actually it was working fine in my last release. So, why now..????

Comment: Its showing thi msg "Your device is not compatible with this version"

Comment: Can you please add the android:xlargeScreens="true" to you manifest, upload to google play and give me your application name to test.

Comment: can you help me for this question [Link...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669582/published-android-application-not-showing-map)